# Read HKLM from windows service on windows 7

Tags: c#, registry

What I need to do is to read an application specific string value from HKLM from a windows service.  The registry hive and values were added using a windows form, a tool for modifying configuration values for the windows service.  I am not able to read the values from my windows service, "Requested registry access is not allowed".  I am trying to open and read as follows:

```
rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(key, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree);
if (rk != null)
{
   value = rk.GetValue(setting).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Can you also post the code from your Winforms app that adds the key? It's clearly a permissions problems, but if the registry key had default permissions for HKLM then it should have worked. That it doesn't work tells me that the does not *not* have the default permissions.

Comment: I rubbed my crystal ball and it said that you're running your service with a 'non-standard' user account.  LocalSystem and friends are very privileged.  The account that runs your winform app usually isn't btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the app and service running under different credentials?  The configuration app may be having registry virtualization applied to it (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965884.aspx).

OR there could be a difference between the bitness of the config app and the service and are seeing different views of the registry (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232.aspx).

Comment: This is my guess (particularly your guess #1)

Comment: Yes, #1 seems to be it.  I prevent the form from creating these keys and create from the service install package.  Still available for update from the form when ran as admin.  And I can read them from the service.

Answer (score 2):

I do this from a Windows .NET Service right now with this code.

```
   public const string REG_KEY_MINE = @"SOFTWARE\Mine\Test";

using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(REG_KEY_MINE, false))
{

    UDP_PORT = (int) key.GetValue("UdpPort", 43221);
    TCP_PORT = (int) key.GetValue("TcpPort", 8005);
}
```

So it is possible you are running your service not under the default Administrator privileges???

Comment: If you're just reading values, you should pass `false` as the second parameter to `OpenSubKey`. You do not need to be running under an administrative account to *read* from HKLM.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I can open this as FALSE.  I will update the code.